# Angular library dependency exposure

Tags: angular, npm, angular-library

When developing an angular library, how do I **hide** my internal dependencies?

I.e. when developing my lib, I did this:

```
yarn add moment-es6
```

However, this should be only an internal dependency - I don't want to force projects using my library to also have `moment-es6`. Is this possible?

PS: I'm following this: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

Answer (score 2):

When you have built your library, and installed in your project it doesn't have a separate node-modules folder. The library's dependencies has to be present in the projects node-modules. So I don't think you can hide internal dependencies.

Like, if an npm package has used jquery, we have to install jquery as well as the main package.

**Example**:  [Angular Datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular7-data-table) It has internal dependency of bootstrap@4.0.0 . So while using it, we must install `bootstrap@4.0.0` along with `angular7-data-table`

Note: I have started building libraries recently. I am not an expert.